# TIME_PERIOD_SHORT - from Events.Record

Tags: google-play-games

I have a request to the Google play games API Events.record that always returns with the error `TIME_PERIOD_SHORT`.  Below is the `Event Record Request Resource`.  Can you help me spot my error?

```
   {
        "timePeriods": [{
            "timePeriod": {
                "periodEndMillis": 1460691042546,
                "periodStartMillis": 1460691039815,
                "kind": "games#eventPeriodRange"
            },
            "updates": [{
                "updateCount": 3,
                "kind": "games#eventUpdateRequest",
                "definitionId": "CgkIiLWAzPEJEAIQAg"
            }],
            "kind": "games#eventPeriodUpdate"
        }],
        "kind": "games#eventRecordRequest",
        "requestId": 1460691043076,
        "currentTimeMillis": 1460691043076
   }
```

My response shows the following error even though in this example this batch period is 2731 millis. I've even pushed it out to 30 seconds and I still get this error.

```
{
        "eventFailures": [],
        "batchFailures": [{
            "range": {
                "periodEndMillis": "1460691042546",
                "periodStartMillis": "1460691039815",
                "kind": "games#eventPeriodRange"
            },
            "failureCause": "TIME_PERIOD_SHORT",
            "kind": "games#eventBatchRecordFailure"
        }],
        "playerEvents": [],
        "kind": "games#eventUpdateResponse"
    }
}
```

Comment: Did some googling but haven't really found any docs that shows the max/min of time periods for recording, compared your codes to what was shown in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/api/events/record#request), and looked around the community for any similar posts, but found nothing. Totally guessing but do you think that the `currentTimeMillis` somehow affects the request? The error is `TIME_PERIOD_SHORT`, and the only short time period difference I'm seeing in your example is between the `currentTimeMillis` and the `periodEndMillis`.

Comment: I unsatisfactorily figured this out. I bumped the time period to 60 seconds and it took the batch.  But what about the case where a user closes a page, you are going to loose the last 60 seconds of events. Thanks much for looking at this with me.